# Why does recursion not continue?

Tags: python-3.x, recursion, maze

I have two list. first list is a maze. It start 'O' and must be finished 'X'.

```
maze_list=[[0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
          [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 'O'],
          [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0],
          [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
          ['X', 1, 0, 1, 0, 0],
          [0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1]]

path_list=[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
           [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
           [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
           [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
           [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
           [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

This part is finding start position.

```
column_size=len(maze_list)                  
row_size=len(maze_list[0])

def find_SF_position(X):
    liste=[]
    for i in range(column_size):
        for j in range(column_size):
            if maze_list[i][j]==X:
                liste.append(i)
                liste.append(j)
    return liste

s_p=find_SF_position('O')     #[1,5]
f_p=find_SF_position('X')     #[4,0]
```

This part is main algorithm. x is for horizontal position. y is for vertical position

```
def solve_maze(maze,road,x,y):
    global column_size
    global row_size
    road[y][x]=1
    print(y,x)
    #left
    if x>0 and maze[y][x-1]==1 and road[y][x-1]==0:
        return solve_maze(maze,road,x-1,y)
    #up
    if y>0 and maze[y-1][x]==1 and road[y][x-1]==0:
        return solve_maze(maze,road,x,y-1)
    #right
    if x>row_size and maze[y][x+1]==1 and road[y][x-1]==0:
        return solve_maze(maze,road,x+1,y)
    #down
    if y>column_size and maze[y+1][x]==1 and road[y][x-1]==0:
        return solve_maze(maze,road,x,y+1)
    if maze[x][y]=='X':
        return path_list
solve_maze(maze_list,path_list,s_p[1],s_p[0])

print(path_list)
```

I can't understand why it isn't working. It's start 'O'(maze_list[1,5]), it fill maze_list[1,4] then stop. 
Finally path_list must be like this

```
path_list=[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
          [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
          [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
          [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
          [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
          [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a few problems in your code:

1. First your *right* and *down* conditions are reversed: `x` can never be greater than `row_size`. What you want to check is that `x` is not on the right border, meaning: `x < row_size - 1`. Same logic goes for the *down* case
2. Seems like you have a little copy-paste issue there: for example the `road` condition for *up* should be: `road[y-1][x]==0`. Same logic goes to all other cases.
3. Your condition to finding the end has a problematic logic: You check if the current cell is the `'X'`, but each step is only taken if there is `1` in the next cell, so how will you get to the `'X'`? For example, after fixing above errors, the output I got was:

   ```
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1]
   [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]
   [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0]
   [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
   [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
   ```

   As you can see, the `'X'` was missed as the condition for *down* was taken at `(4, 1)` and a dead-end was reached
4. Lastly, what happens if you reach a dead-end? Your algorithm always takes the first step with conditions met, but what happens when you encounter an intersection? You need to check all possible paths. That's the point of recursion. The way you did it now doesn't add much over a loop.